# Templated class method definition syntax

Tags: c++, templates

Class definition:

```
template<class K, class V,
         unsigned hashFunc(const K&),
         int compFunc(const K&,const K&)=&_compFunc<K> > class X {};
```

I want to define a class method outside of the class code block. like so:

```
template<class K, class V,
         unsigned hashFunc(const K&),
         int compFunc(const K&,const K&)=&_compFunc<K> >
X<K, V, hashFunc, compFunc>::X() { }
```

g++ v.4.4.3 returns

> error: default argument for template
>   parameter for class enclosing ‘X::X()’

Why is the compiler complaining and how can i make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't declare or define a constructor for `X`. In addition, you had repeated the default template parameters in your attempted X::X definition.

Here's the fixed code, `main`-ified:

```
template<class K, class V,
         unsigned hashFunc(const K&),
         int compFunc(const K&,const K&)=&_compFunc<K> > 
class X 
{ 
    X();
};

template<class K, class V,
         unsigned hashFunc(const K&),
         int compFunc(const K&,const K&) >
X<K, V, hashFunc, compFunc>::X() { }

int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be repeating the default template parameter :

```
template<class K, class V,
         unsigned hashFunc(const K&),
         int compFunc(const K&,const K&)>
X<K, V, hashFunc, compFunc>::X() { /* ... */ }
```

As pointed out by John Dibling, class X must obviously also declare the constructor, but I assumed the code was removed for clarity.